# while on jquery click event got value for first time but second time it comes to empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

While on jquery click event got value for first time but second time it comes to empty

**JS:**

```
$(".topPanel").live('click', (function(e) {

    form = $(e.target).attr("name");
    content = $("." + form);    
    $(".show_panel1").html("");
    $(".show_panel1").html(content);
    $(".show_panel1").show();

}));
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="topPanel"  >
   <span id="5" name="panther" style="background: #990000;" class="span_1">  
                   Panther</span>
   <span id="6" name="lion" style="background: #009900;" class="span_1">
                   Lion</span>         
 </div>

 <div class="show_panel1" >
     <label class="label">welcome</label>
 </div>
 <div class="tiger" >
     <label  class="label">i am panther</label>
 </div>
 <div class="lion" >
     <label  class="label">i am lion</label>
 </div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.label
{
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight:lighter; 
    color: #FF990000;
    float:inherit;
    margin:10mm;
}

.topPanel
{
    float: left; 
    color:#000000;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% orange; 
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
}

.span_1
{
   float: left; 
    height: 40px; 
    width:5%; 
    padding:20px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

​

Comment: Where is .topPanel and What is getFunction()

Comment: My code beautifier isn't working very well for html, thanks Vega.

Comment: i added .topPanel and getFunction is different scenario so ignore it , thanks! now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines don't make sense:

```
content = $("." + form);    
$(".show_panel1").html(content);
```

`content` is a jQuery object.  You can't put a jQuery object into the html of another object.  Perhaps you meant:

```
var content = $("." + form);    
$(".show_panel1").html(content.html());
```

This would get the HTML from the content object and put it into `.show_panel1`.  Note, I also declared the `content` variable to be a local variable rather than allowing it to be an implicit global variable which is bad.

---

Please show us the HTML that contains `class="form"` so we can see what you're actually trying to do here.

Also, `.live()` has been deprecated (you should no longer use it).  Replace it with `.on()` (for recent versions of jQuery) or `.delegate()` (for older versions of jQuery).

Comment: form is a variable in which we are passing a class

Comment: @ jfriend00 i declared the content as global variable in my main code this one is reference to that

Answer (score 2):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/azeyeb/2/edit)**

```
$(".topPanel").on('click', 'span', function(){

    var form = $(this).attr("name");
    var content = $("." + form).html();    
    $(".show_panel1").html(content).show();

});
```

P.S: not sure why you need `.show()` but here it is!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the culprit

```
$(".show_panel1").html(content);
```

You were passing a selector to HTML

It should be

```
$(".show_panel1").html(content.html());
```

Also `<div class="tiger" >`

is supposed to be  `<div class="panther" >`

You are trying to call the **tiger class** which is not present

[Check this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ppV7Z/) with all the Updated changes